# Один и тот же Activity в двух вкладках TabHost

Tags: android, gui

У меня есть табхост с несколькими вкладками. Мне нужно, что бы один и тот же активити, без изменений, без пересоздания отображался в двух  вкладках.      То есть, мне не нужно 2 экземпляра одного Активити, нужен именно один. Что бы, на пример, текст, введенный в поле на первой вкладке, можно было продолжить вводить на второй вкладке.

Другими словами, мне нужно, что бы была иллюзия открытия второй вкладки, а на самом деле была открыта первая...

У меня в обеих вкладках отображается карта, и мне нужно что бы при скроллинге карты в одной вкладке она скроллилась и в другой, и т. п.

Надеюсь, выразил вопрос понятно...

Заранее большое спасибо всем!

Comment: Зря надеетесь. Непонятно совсем ничего. Как можно отображать активити во вкладках? Если все совсем наоборот - табхост принадлежит активити... Зачем нужно редактировать один и тот же текст в разных вкладках? Какой в этом смысл?

Comment: а что в таком случае отображается во вкладках?
мне нужно в двух вкладках отобразить почти одно и то же содержимое. во второй вкладке один элемент просто должен быть спрятан.

Comment: а может сделать вкладки фиктивными? Мне кажется, ТС пытается использовать вкладки вместо radiobutton'a.

Comment: нет. у меня всего 4 вкладки, и всего лиш 2 из них должны быть "фиктивными"

Хотя это может и проканает... можно просто поверх той части табВиджета, которая переключает "одинаковые" вкладки, поставить кнопки...

Comment: Но я все таки рекомендовал бы не делать хаки и сделать просто две копии активити. А содержимое можно через bundle перенести.

Comment: А ссылкой на пример более-менее понятный можете кинуть?

Comment: пример? кто мешает в onPause сохранять содержимое, в onResume его восстанавливать.
Можно воспользоваться тем, что система регулярно сама вызывает  onSaveInstanceState, когда ей нужно сохранить состояние активити ( в том числе текст, позиции).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всем спасибо, пришла в голову идея, которая мне подходит.

Я просто выставил

```
mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mTabHost.getTabWidget().setCurrentTab(1);

        }
    });
```

OnClickLictener на нужные мне элементы ТабВиджета, и просто визуально меняю активную вкладку в ТабВиджете.

Answer (score 2):

Короче ход размышления... мой.. Есть задача (описанная в вопросе), так вот, логично предположить, что если я ввожу текст в активити1 (а1) и надо что бы он продолжался в а2, я должен

1. Или сделать 2ю вкладку и туда постить актуальный текст
2. Или подставлять а1, чистить ее от старого текста и писать дальше и где-то в бэкграунде - писать текст целиком

Наверно, можно еще сделать просто слайдер - типа переключатель вкладок, а внизу просто держать одну вьюху.

Comment: как то мутно написано.

Comment: на одной волне с ТС =)

Comment: Спасибо, но ввод текста я привел, как пример... мне нужно не конкретно текст переносить

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял ход ваших "мыслев", то можно сделать следующее

При нажатии на первую вкладку отображаете то, что вам нужно. А при нажатии на вторую "Фиктивную" вкладку открываете ту же активити, НО уже скажем с параметром `fiction=True` или `second_tab` - не важно. И там уже скрываете то, что вам надо скрыть. Возможно, что и введенный текст также надо будет передавать через `bundle`.

От себя хочу добавить, что если у вас уже присутствует такая "странная" логика, то вы явно что-то делает не так. Попробуйте пересмотреть архитектуру вашего приложения.

Comment: да будь моя воля, я бы сделал одну вкладку из этих двух... к сожалению такую "архитектуру" мне диктуют сверху...